# how to get json data one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my script in getting the json file:

```
$.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json)
    {
        var imgFloorList= "";

        $.each(json.floorTile, function(){
            imgFloorList += '<img src= "' + this.img_src + '">';
        });
        $('.img-container').append(imgFloorList);
    })
```

I want to get one image in json file and put it in the div img-container. What should I do so i can only get one image and not all the images I have in the json file?

Comment: Please share a sample JSON response you get.

Comment: `$('.img-container').append('<img src= "' + json.floorTile[0].img_src + '">');`

Comment: Please add sample json and additionally, which image do you want to append - whats the logic to select an image from list of images

Comment: If it's a specific image, can you ID it specifically? The you can set an `if` condition

Comment: If you want only one or first image then you do not need `$.each` loop.

Comment: can you log the json object for us?

Comment: this is my json file 

{
 "floorTile": [
  {
   "img_src": "assets/images/tile1.jpg"
  },
  {
   "img_src": "assets/images/tile2.jpg"
  },
  {
   "img_src": "assets/images/tile3.jpg"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: And this is my html file 

 <div class="img-container">
</div>
<div class="img-container">
</div>
<div class="img-container">
</div>

I want to put the images one by one in the img-container

Answer (score 0):

Below is a complete example, you can have a look how I've done it and change your solution accordingly

**Controller:**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult GetProducts()
    {
        var p1 = new Product { name = "fruit", img_src = "http://kingofwallpapers.com/fruit/fruit-005.jpg" };
        var p2 = new Product { name = "vegetables", img_src = "http://blogs.extension.iastate.edu/foodsavings/files/2014/06/vegetables-variety.jpg" };
        return Json(new List<Product> { p1, p2 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string img_src { get; set; }
}
```

**View:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        debugger;
        var jsonURL = '@Url.Action("GetProducts","Test")';

        $.getJSON(jsonURL, function (data) {
            var img = '<img src="' + data[0].img_src + '" style="width:100px;height:100px;">';
            $(".img-container").append(img);
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="img-container">
</div>
```